# Accumulate specific rows from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Pandas dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Notice that for each task there are exactly 2 rows: row for begin and and row for end of task.
I need to create another dataframe with columns **Task, StartTime, EndTime** where each row will represent task and it's lifetime.
There is an ugly way to do it (using iteration). Is there an elegant way?

Comment: sort by action -> groupby task ->apply/cast to a pd.Series -> unstack

Comment: Check out `df.pivot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pandas.pivot()` function you can simply do it like this assuming df is your dataframe:

```
new_df = df.pivot(index="Task", columns="Action", values="DateTime")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `set_index` and `unstack`:

```
>>> (df.set_index(['Task', 'Action'])['DateTime'].unstack()
       .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None))

   Task                    begin                      end
0     1  2022-05-04 16:07:42.580  2022-05-04 16:07:53.565
```